# Getting currently logged in user from AD ( Instead of NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE )

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

I have a c# asp.net web application where i need to get the currently signed in user ( Windows authenticaion - Active directory )

I changed the authentication in ISS(7.5) to windows authentication and prevented anonymous access in web.config

However when i use " System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() " i do not get my own user credentials but NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE.

I tried having iis use my account for the application pool ( just for testing ) but this just messes evrything up.

Any idea what i can do to get my own user credentials ?

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`

Comment: Was this ever resolved and how?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns the identity of the account the web application is running as.

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` returns the identity of the logged in user. Often [when you're in a page or controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx), you can just do `User.Identity`. When in doubt, read the documentation!

Comment: In this case it is a Sitecore website and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity gives me {Sitecore.Security.Principal.SitecoreIdentity} and not <companydomain>/<username>

Inside the sitecoreIdentity is a user but this is the currently logged in user in sitecore extranet/anonymous

Comment: @Timon The `.Name` property contains the username. According to [this blog post](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/sitecore-users-and-c/), that is expected. When a user it not logged in, they will have the account `extranet/anonymous`. But once they log in it sounds like you'll see their actual domain and username.